# Unable to get data message in FCM using firebase admin SDK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase admin SDK in NodeJS and trying to send push notification from server.My problem is I am not getting data part in my notification(account and balance).It is only showing notification part(title and body).

I have implemented server side code something like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./my_service_account.json");

admin.initializeApp({

credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: "https://<myapp name>.firebaseio.com"
});

var payload = {
          notification: {
            title: "Hello",
            body: "How are you."
          },  
          data: {
            account: "Savings",
            balance: "$3020.25"
          } 
        };

 admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken,payload)
 .then((response) =>{

                         console.log("Response", response); 

                    }).catch((error) => {

                         console.log("Error", error);
                    });
```

On client side I am doing like this below:

```
public class MessagingReceive extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        handleData(data);
    }
  }

private void handleData(Map<String,String> data){

       String title = data.get("account");
       String body = data.get("balance");

    Intent intent = new Intent(MessagingReceive.this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(body);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
  }
}
```

Someone let me know how can I get data part in my notification. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: does `remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0` is `true` ?

Comment: I am trying to log value using if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){

            Log.d("Data",remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
            
        }

Comment: But there is no value in logs.

Comment: what do you see when you `Log.d("Data",remoteMessage.getData());` ?

Comment: I am getting data in MessagingReceive activity but my launcher activity is MainActivity so how can I get data in logs.

Comment: write `Log.d("Data",remoteMessage.getData());` inside `onMessageReceived` just below the `super` call , then go out from your app , and keep your device plugged-in , send a notification and look at your `Logcat`

Comment: Yeah I checked it but nothing is showing in log cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) in Receive messages in an Android app section

> **Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, **and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity**.

Now , according to [Notification messages with optional data payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload)

> App behavior when receiving messages that include both notification and data payloads depends on whether the app is in the background or the foreground essentially, whether or not it is active at the time of receipt.

- When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, **and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification**.
- When in the foreground, your app receives a **message object with both payloads available**.

so during the time the app is in the background , the `notification` obj in your `payload` is available in order to build a standart notification (title,body).

to get the `payload` `data` object when the user taps on the notification for example is implemented by `intent` .

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
String account;
String balance;
String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        account = data.get("account");
        balance = data.get("balance");
 }
  handleData(title,body,account,balance);
}

private void(String body , String title , Stirng account , String balance){

Intent intent = new Intent(MessagingReceive.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("account",account);
intent.putExtra("balance",balance);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: So How can I implement it when my app is in background state or killed.

Comment: OK.. so If I want to redirect to some activity on notification click for that do I need to add some on click in payload on server side.