# android: Make action according to FCM notification's data

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I working on an android app that use firebase cloud messaging to receive notifications, I send notification and data from fcm to my app, I want to make an action according to data of fcm when click on notification bar when my app is in background, I use below code which work correctly when app in foreground, but on background it's just open app without making any action:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    val TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService"
    var count = 0
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.data != null && remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            val id = remoteMessage.data["id"].toString()
            val activityName = remoteMessage.data["view"].toString()
            val intent = Intent(this, NewsDetailesActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            NewsDetailesActivity.currentNewId = id
            startActivity(intent)

            showNotification(remoteMessage.notification?.title, remoteMessage.notification?.body,activityName,id)
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?,activityName:String,id:String?) {
        var intent = Intent(this, NewsDetailesActivity::class.java)
        if (activityName == "news")
        {
            intent = Intent(this, NewsDetailesActivity::class.java)
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        NewsDetailesActivity.currentNewId = id!!
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )

        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channelId")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_orang)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build())
        count += 1

    }
}
```

How can I modify my app to work in background?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56665648/11555903) answer about data payload when your app is in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution as below:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    val TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService"
    var count = 0
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.data != null && remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.data)
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification(data :Map<String,String>) {
        var intent = Intent()
        var title =data["title"]
        var body =data["body"]
        var activityName = data["view"]

        if (activityName == "news")
        {
            intent = Intent(this, NewsDetailesActivity::class.java)
            var id = data["id"]
            NewsDetailesActivity.currentNewId = id!!
        }
      
        else if(activityName == "url") {
            val url  = data["url"]
            val b = Bundle()
            val uris = Uri.parse(url)
            intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uris)
            b.putBoolean("new_window", true)
            intent.putExtras(b)
        }


        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)



        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channelId")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_orang)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(count, notificationBuilder.build())
        count += 1
    }
}
```

And on my API I removed notification key, and just send data payload.

Answer (score 0):

Always send data object in the notification API call
Like this:

```
{  
    "data" : {
      "body" : "Watch Live Footlball Streaming online & stay updated with fastest live match scores on Hotstar",
            "content_available" : true,
            "title" : "Brazil vs. Denmark",
            "isScheduled":false,
            "scheduledTime":"2020-03-03 12:20:00",
            "stationCode":"PNB",
            "groupId":2

    },
  "to" : "epGANq1gDpE:APA91bHEuHS_QRILwI9GJ-x8Sz4DKjHRN0KX23R5TGx9HyRAN8caghmakMSnRavOf4Qwnmni3ByVRndvMjmMvfQnVt-2g6AgI5OB1-0vK3HQWDdhAjb155KWnYLXgEn763hSSbPX7tFm",
    "priority" : "high"

}
```

Also, check this sample to run in the background.
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-kotlin-notifications-fcm

Comment: But that is not worked for both iOS and android, the iOS notification API require a "notification" key in payload, how can I send same notification payload for both environments with an action taken in that notification?